# Minimum moves to checkmate?

Tags: analysis, statistics, checkmate

What is the minimum number of moves, counting both sides, in which a checkmate can be made?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The precise answer to your question is **four half-moves**. The only checkmate possible in two moves is by Black - `1.f3 e5 2.g4 Qh4#` (This mate is known as [Fool's Mate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fool%27s_mate)). Slight variations may occur (in White's move order or in the distance Black's e-pawn or White's f-pawn is advanced):

```
1.g4 e5 2.f3 Qh4#
1.f3 e6 2.g4 Qh4#
1.g4 e6 2.f3 Qh4#
1.g4 e5 2.f4 Qh4#
1.f4 e5 2.g4 Qh4#
1.g4 e6 2.f4 Qh4#
1.f4 e6 2.g4 Qh4#
```

If White is to mate, a minimum of five half-moves (three moves) is required, for example `1.e4 f6 2.d4 g5 3.Qh5#` (with similar variations possible).